# TikTok embeds not working within TikTok app webview

Tags: javascript, html, tiktok, tiktok-api

I've placed a few TikTok videos on my website using the [TikTok embed API](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/embed-videos/), however when clicking my site url from my TikTok bio, TikTok's in app web view redirects my to a full page view of my embedded video instead of my website.

I have to click back three times to get to my home page and once there the embedded videos don't work.

[image][image][image]